# Can I create an android app that uses youtube API to download videos, forward them to the user, and display them offline (in-app if needed)?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

My current umbrella idea for an app is:

- Provide the user choices for downloading/tracking content (for example: the [archives of fanfiction.net](http://fanfiction.net/book), RSS blog entries, or in this case, youtube channels with videos)
- Send download requests to the server, to download, ready, compress, or help in any way to lighten the download when sent to the user at a later date.
- Download the item in the background, notify users when requested item, show on "homescreen" when downloaded pre-emptively.
- Cache the result depending on user interaction with the item, when "done", flag for low priority upon clean sweep.
- (based on optimistic wifi connection intervals, download content when you can, and forward those queued download requests when connecting to the server)

My question is: 

Can i include youtube in this app (and apply to this concept)?

Can i make requests from the server, which downloads the video at different resolutions and later distribute it to clients?

Is it allowed for a third party to download those videos and later distribute them, but link back to the original content?

Most of the youtube API and TOS is foggy about exactly this scenario.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns YouTube policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Embedding

Embedding is fine, they even provide the [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) to make this easier.

## Download rules

A lot of sites and apps ignore this, but section 9.1 of the [TOS](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) says this:

> 9.1 With the exception of Content submitted to the Service by you, all other Content on the Service is either owned by or licensed to YouTube, and is subject to copyright, trade mark rights, and other intellectual property rights of YouTube or YouTube's licensors... **Such Content may not be downloaded**, copied, reproduced, distributed, transmitted, broadcast, displayed, sold, licensed, or otherwise exploited for any other purpose whatsoever without the prior written consent of YouTube or, where applicable, YouTube's licensors. YouTube and its licensors reserve all rights not expressly granted in and to their Content.

So without permission in writing from YouTube you are not allowed to do this. They have been known to threaten to sue websites for this. [Source](https://torrentfreak.com/google-threatens-to-sue-huge-youtube-mp3-conversion-site-120619/)

Comment: thank you, that clears things up, i might contact youtube about trying this out then

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can embed Youtube player in your app.
2. Yes, I saw many apps on the Google Play Store, app market (not official), or website provide these features.
3. AFAIK, it's depend on which video which has copyright or free for everyone. But in most of the case: No, without permission in writing from YouTube you are not allowed to do this.

Comment: RE 1.: My main concept is to download the videos, to make them watchable at any time, the youtube player connects to the internet at runtime, unless it can view local cached versions, or somehow trick it, it is not what i am looking for

Comment: My Youtube app allow me to download video that available even offline. But if you want to watch it, you still need to open Youtube app and keep the screen on.

Comment: What app do you mean?

Comment: Youtube official app.

Comment: you probably mean [youtube go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.mango&hl=en&rdid=com.google.android.apps.youtube.mango)

Comment: No, It's the same https://ig.howtoisolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Find-option-for-save-video-offline.jpeg but for Android

Comment: ...i can assure you, i have never seen that option there, nor have 99% of youtube's mobile users, nor does that site give any indication *how* to make the button appear, or tag requirements for it.
I'm betting you need youtube red, but it doesnt even show *that*.

Comment: It's curious, my Youtube app is official, and not Youtube red.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube api officially allows you to just embed and play only. Downloading YouTube videos is violating their rules